# insert date value to mysqli database- not posting value

Tags: php, database, mysqli

Hi please this is not a duplicate question... have tried previous issue does not work for me.

Am having issue posting date input to database. I have about five date field input in my application but i only get the date_of_birth posted, using the same concept the rest of the post not posting.

this shot indicate the value works but then on the DB is showing 0000-00-00

here is my code
**html**

```
           <div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-md-2">
                <label for="date_of_birth"><strong>DOB:</strong> </label>
                <input type="text" name="date_of_birth" class="form-control underline-input" value='<?php echo $date_of_birth; ?>' placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD">
            </div> 
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-md-2">
                <label for="dob"><strong>DOB 2:</strong> </label>
                <input type="text" name="dob" class="form-control underline-input" value='<?php echo $dob; ?>' placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD">
            </div>
```

**php**

```
        <?php

    // start session
    session_start();
    error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    // include connection
    require_once('include/connection.php');
    //   require_once('include/pdo-config.php');

    // if user is loggin, redirected to homepage
    if(isset($_SESSION['user_type'])){
    header('Location: index.php');
    }

            $userId = $_SESSION['user_id'];
            $userName = $_SESSION['user_name'];
                            //         $errors = array();
                            //         $data = array();
    $error = [] ;
    $status = "";
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))    {
     // recommended solution
          $firstname = trim($_POST['firstname']);
          $lastname = trim($_POST['lastname']);
          $date_of_birth = trim($_POST['date_of_birth']);
          $dob = trim($_POST['dob']);;                                                  
          $created_at = $_POST['created_at']; 

                        $created_at = date('Y-m-d');                                            
                        $dob = date('Y-m-d');                                           
                        $date_of_birth = date('Y-m-d');
                   if(!($stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO task (firstname, lastname, date_of_birth, dob, created_at) 
                      VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)"))) {
                      echo "Prepare failed: (" . $con->errno . ")" . $con->error;
                  }

                  if(!$stmt->bind_param('sssss', $firstname, $lastname, $date_of_birth, $dob,  $created_at)){
                   echo "Binding paramaters failed:(" . $stmt->errno . ")" . $stmt->error;
                  }

                  if(!$stmt->execute()){
                   echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno .")" . $stmt->error;
                  }

            $stmt->close();

                  if($stmt) {
                    $status = '<div class="alert alert-success">New Task Added successfully!</div>';

                            }else{
                    $status = '<span class="alert alert-danger">Error in your query</div>';
                  }

                            $stmt->close();
      }
```

Maybe you will have eyes that i don't... have tried different angle no luck. i also turned on my error report and here is the error am getting for that http://prntscr.com/f64zz4

**UPDATE**
**html**

```
                <form name="task" role="task" id="task_form" data-parsley-validate="" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post" autocomplete='off'>

    <div class="row">
    <!--                                    <div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-md-2">
    <label for="id"><strong>Client ID:</strong> </label>
        <input type="text" name="id" class="form-control underline-input" id="input07" placeholder="01..." disabled>                                            
    </div>                                          -->
    <div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-md-2">
    <label for="firstname"><strong>First Name:</strong> </label>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" class="form-control underline-input" value='<?php echo $_POST['firstname']; ?>' placeholder="first name"
             data-parsley-trigger="change"
             data-parsley-range="[3, 15]"
             required-no>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-md-2">
    <label for="lastname"><strong>Last name:</strong> </label>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" class="form-control underline-input" value='<?php echo $_POST['lastname']; ?>' placeholder="last name"
             data-parsley-trigger="change"
             data-parsley-range="[3, 15]"
             required-no>
    </div>  

    <div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-md-2">
                <label for="date_of_birth"><strong>DOB:</strong> </label>
                <input type="text" name="date_of_birth" class="form-control underline-input" value='<?php echo $date_of_birth; ?>' placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD">
                </div> 
                <div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-md-2">
                <label for="dob"><strong>DOB 2:</strong> </label>
                <input type="text" name="dob" class="form-control underline-input" value='<?php echo $dob; ?>' placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD">
                </div> 

    </div>
```

**PHP**

```
            if(isset($_POST['submit']))    {
            // recommended solution
                    $firstname = trim($_POST['firstname']);
                    $lastname = trim($_POST['lastname']);
            $date_of_birth = trim($_POST['date_of_birth']);
            $dob = trim($_POST['dob']);;                                                    
                    $created_at = $_POST['created_at']; 

                    $created_at = date('Y-m-d');                                            
                    $dob = date('Y-m-d');                                           
                    $date_of_birth = date('Y-m-d');
                 if(!($stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO task (firstname, lastname, date_of_birth, dob, created_at) 
                                            VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)"))) {
                                            echo "Prepare failed: (" . $con->errno . ")" . $con->error;
            }
```

**DATABASE SCHEMA**
http://prntscr.com/f65ihm

Comment: Where do you get the `created_at`?

Comment: what format did you choose to store the date in the database?

Comment: `created_at` insert automatically when the form is posted to the db.... http://prntscr.com/f6538n

Comment: @Kaddath i used date... but then have tried timestamp as well here http://prntscr.com/f653w8

Comment: Post your complete error messages in your post. It seems like you are overwriting your form inputs with `date()` commands.

Comment: `$dob = trim($_POST['dob']);;`

Comment: also add backticks to your columns and table name ````

Comment: @Akin this is me trying everything out even when i take that out still the same issue

Comment: @lekan oshodi if see your coding logic is bit different from mine. As i understood your question you want to insert `dob` in this format `2017-05-10`. Am i right. that's it

Comment: @Lekan remove all these `$created_at = date('Y-m-d');                                            
                        $dob = date('Y-m-d');                                           
                        $date_of_birth = date('Y-m-d');` You are ovewriting what you have from `$_POST`

Comment: @RST sorry i don't understand what complete error messesage... i think your refering to the warning and notice error i posted above... sorry i can't as the rest of them is the location of my file and error in line number

Comment: @PavanBaddi... that right or in any format at all as long as the value date is posted instead of `0000-00-00`

Comment: @Akin... thanks for input to be honest it wasn't if there to begin with until i started messing with it. i will do that again

Comment: @lekanoshodi maybe you should switch back to timestamps, they usually avoid localization problems for date formats. From the beginning of the error sent, it seems that the problem comes from the `created_at` which is not found in `$_POST`. can you check if it corresponds to the error line?

Comment: @lekan oshodi of then let meet make a demo

Comment: @Akin have amend that but no luck think

Comment: @Lekan. add `var_dump` at the top your php script. Let's make sure you have everything coming from your html form via `$_POST`

Comment: @lekanoshodi note: if `created_at` is set to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` in mysql, i think you should not try to set it in the request, beacause it will be set automatically. Try to remove this line `$created_at = $_POST['created_at'];` and set only the 4 first parameters in the query

Comment: am using codeanywhere for my out of desk modification... i can share just the page with you guy's to have a look... but then you might just need a quick signup if you don't have acct

Comment: just post your html form as well, with your updated code

Comment: @Kaddath thanks let me try that

Comment: also post your database schema. it would help filtering the root of the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can do it. Here i have user `mysqli prepared statement`.

The dates are inserted in the same format as you wanted.

HERE IS THE IMAGE OF MYSQ DATABASE TABLE

[image: TABLE IMAGE]

HERE IS MY PHP AND MYSQLI CODE:

```
    <?php

    $link = new mysqli ('localhost','root','admin','demo1');
    if($link->connect_error){
        die ("connection failed".$link->connect_error);
    }

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $firstname = trim($_POST['fname']);
        $lastname = trim($_POST['lname']);
        $date_of_birth = trim($_POST['date_of_birth']);
        $dob = trim($_POST['dob']);
        $created_at = date('Y-m-d');

        $sql = $link->stmt_init();

        if($sql->prepare("INSERT INTO demodate (fname,lname,date_of_birth,dob,created_at) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)")){
            $sql->bind_param('sssss',$firstname,$lastname,$date_of_birth,$dob,$created_at);
            if($sql->execute()){
                echo "Successfully inserted";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Failed to inserted";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Error Inserting".$link->error;
        }
    }
?>
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="Enter First Name...">
            <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Enter Last Name...">
            <input type="date" name="date_of_birth" placeholder="Enter Date of Birth YYYY/MM/DD...">
            <input type="date" name="dob" placeholder="Enter DOB YYYY/MM/DD...">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

### Hope i have answered your question if something to be answered you can freely ask

Comment: OK gr8t job Pavan... i used your sample in my query directly but it doesn't still... The i test it by creating a new file and dump your sample and change the connection to mine and it works great. So it must be the way i structured my code

Comment: Thanks for all your input everyone... really appreciate it... Now i need to recheck my code to reflect these.